# How to hide div when user clicks other place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide the div with id = SDWN when the user clicks any other place in the document.

```
<div id="SDWN" onclick="OKIJUYG()">
    <img src="../img/lupa.png" ID="ILDSIB" onclick="OKIJUYGA()" >
</div>
<div id="ATSIMD">
    <div class="arrow-up" id="SHS">
    </div>
<div id="Vsauceisgenius" tabindex="-1"  >
    <img src="../img/x.png" id="CTSO" href="#">
    <input type="text" placeholder="People" id="IMOHD">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="DPMM">
    <P></P>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hashtags" id="IMOHDS">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="DPMMM">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try to do that didn't work? Did you search google/ check other posts/read the api of jquery?

Comment: i searched but i didnt find anything useful.I tried to do that with onfocus but it didnt work

Comment: Is #SDWN displayed when the page is loaded?

Comment: yes onclick #SDWN #ATSIMD opens i need #ATSIMD to get closed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to check if the element was clicked, and if it was not, then hide it:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target !== $("#ATSIMD") && event.target !== $("#SHS") {
        $("#ATSIMD").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: The question was unclear, you added *I need to hide the div with id = SDWN when the user clicks any other place in the document.* The title simply said *other place*. I posted my answer before the edit. Don't down-vote a perfectly legitimate answer because of a badly formed question.

Comment: @Script47 the question was unclear and the code was all in one line, thats why I suggested a change, and rewrote the question as I understood it. He accepted the change, so I guess that was what he wanted. If not, then I am sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: My post was made prior to the update, so instead of down voting, why not inform me to check the update. You don't get a notification when an update is made to a post so how do you expect me to update my post without knowing?

Comment: @Script47 I said I am sorry bro. The question was unclear, and I edited it to make it more visible. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).click()` to hide div on click anywhere. Then add click binding to your div and use [**event.stopPropagation()**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to stop event bubbling.

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#SDWN").hide();
});

/* Clicks within the dropdown won't make
   it past the dropdown itself */
$("#SDWN").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"Other Place" I think is any other item other than `#SDWN`, try this code:

```
if (document.body.addEventListener){
  document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target == document.getElementById("SDWN")) return;
     document.getElementById("SDWN").style.display = "none";
  }); 
} else if (document.body.attachEvent){
  document.body.attachEvent('onclick', function(e){
    if(e.target == document.getElementById("SDWN")) return;
    document.getElementById("SDWN").style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

Try yourself:

https://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/pyptkzms/

This solution not need **jQuery**.

But I don't like this solution, meybe you can find an other one.